# How to draw shape inside of JPanel that is inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, jpanel

I have issue with drawing shapes inside of JPanel that I already added using Netbeans GUI. Now, I have no idea where to add code for drawing a circle inside of that JPanel and how to insert and call it in the JPanel that is sitting empty now, waiting for this shape to be drawn. I already set up destination JPanel to be Flow layout.
Netbeans Designer created a big class in which I have entire frame with this JPanel, and I want to keep it inside of it as I can't really add it any other way because Designer doesn't let me change main initComponents method in which all components are sitting now. I have been reading tutorials and previous posts but noone really encountered this using Netbeans Designer.
SO can someone just help me with adding proper method in this frame class and how to call it from JPanel I want to draw in. JPanel is 50x50 pixels.

So as per @Abra, I changed some code:

so I made a new Circle Class, adjusted it a bit as I don't want to create a new frame but put this in JPanel.

```
public class Circle extends JPanel {
Color color;
public void circle(Color color)    {
    this.color = color;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (30,30));
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)    {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(0, 0, r, r);
    g.setColor(color);
}
private void showGUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(this, FlowLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}       
}
```

Then I opened JPanel in Designer, and added code to run it, in initComponents method like this:

```
circlePanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(40, 40));
    new Circle().showGUI();
    PanelDS.add(circlePanel);
```

circlePanel is destination for this drawing and is inside PanelDS itself. It doesn't work this way tho, but Netbeans shows no errors in code. Additionally, how can I forward color to circle class.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a basic working example. For a more complex example you can check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Comment: Hi @camickr, I read all of this, but I still can't wrap my head around where to put what, as every example has so many classes and I am afraid I can't really follow, is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Your reliance on Netbeans designer isn't helping you.  Follow the tutorials @camickr linked, and learn to code your own Swing components.

Comment: @Dino, *is there an elegant solution to this?* - you have already been given an elegant solution. Start with the working solution from the tutorial. Then once you understand how it works you add another piece of functionality and test. When that works add more functionality and test. Don't try to write the entire application before testing!

Answer (score 1):

In order to draw on a `JPanel` you need to override the `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel`. In order to override the method, you need to create a class that extends `JPanel`. I don't think that there exists a GUI designer that can generate the required code for you. So you have to write the code of the class that extends `JPanel`.

Here is a minimal example. It displays a blue circle.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Drawing2 extends JPanel {
    private JFrame  frame;

    public Drawing2() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(25, 25, 50, 50);
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Drawing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Drawing2().showGui();
    }
}
```

Here's what you should see when you run the above code.

[image: Blue circle]

Comment: Hi @abra, I added a code to post that I changed for my program, it still does not work.

Comment: @Dino if you want me to debug your code for you, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Abra, it is huge, I uploaded my project in netbeans to google Drive, if you can check it please. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Vv4LBaVxS1j44Xt4pZ01PVF8CLG-38T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dino, *it is huge,* - why would you write a huge program to learn a concept? When learning a new concept start with something small and build up. You have already been given a link to the Swing tutorial which contains a working example and explanations of how the code works.

Comment: @Dino, Also the code from the tutorial shows the proper way to create the GUI. All GUI components should be created on the EDT. That is why I post a link to the tutorial instead of creating a simple example, which would duplicate what is found in the tutorial anyway.